# Let $T_1$ and $T_2$ be diagonalisable operators on a real vector space $V$. Does it follow that $T_1+T_2$ is a diagonalisable operator?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T_1$ and $T_2$ be diagonalisable operators on a real vector space $V$. Does it follow that $T_1+T_2$ is a diagonalisable operator?

My intution says no. But I can't find any counterexample.

Comment: If they commute, then $T_1+T_2$ is diagonalisable

Answer (score 3):

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
5 & 1 \\
1 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1 \\
-1 & 5
\end{array}
\right)
$$

If you could diagonalise 
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
6 & 2 \\
0 & 6
\end{array}
\right)
$$
you could also do
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
3 & 1 \\
0 & 3
\end{array}
\right)
$$